# отослать render на другой вид

Tags: yii2

есть контролер cartController  с таким рендерингом

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPjax) {
     return $this->renderPartial('_success');
   } else {
     return $this->goBack();
}
```

вот вид cart/_success.php

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax']); ?>
<p><?= \yii\helpers\Html::encode('Добавлено') ?></p>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

есть необходимость добавить такой рендер

```
$this->renderPartial('адресс нужного вида',['pluss'=>1]);
```

но проблема в том что нужны й вид находиться в виде layouts/main.php как можно отправить такой рендер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить такой код

```
$this->renderPartial('/layouts/main',['pluss'=>1]);
```